# Law of total expectation and Information.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading a paper by Glostom and Milgrom on "Bid/Ask transaction prices". Here is the gist of the issue I am having.  $F_t$ is the current information / filtration. $Z_t$ is a random variable. $A$ is the ask price. $V$ is the random unknown fair value of a stock.  The claim is below.

$E[V 1_{\{Z_t > A\}} | S_t] = E[V | S_t, \{Z_t > A\}] P(Z_t > A | S_t)$

I kinda see that this is the law of total expectation. I have seen and know how to prove when the conditioning is over single sets, I am not sure how I can extend a measure theoretic argument over to this situation. In general how does one prove this to conditioning over any set of information sets.

Answer (score -1):

What is $S_t$ in this situation?

Edit: If $S_t$ is also a filtration and $Z_t$ is $S_t$-measurable I don't really see what the conditioning $S_t,\{Z_t>A\}$ is supposed to mean. I guess they probably mean the random variable $Y=E[V|S_t,\{Z_t>A\}]$ which is $0$ outside of $\{Z_t>A\}$ and equal to $c\cdot E[V|S_t]$ inside of $\{Z_t>A\}$. Then the question of how to choose this $c$ value is directly related to your question. $c$ needs to make $Y$ a random variable, i.e. $E[Y]=1$, and for that you need to inflate it to account for the "lost" expectation by setting $Y=0$ outside of $\{Z_t>A\}$. Therefore $c=\frac{1}{P(Z_t>A|S_t)}$. If you enter this into your equation you will see that the equation holds.

Comment: This is a model of bid ask spreads in the Market, $S_t$ is essentially sigma algebra of all the bids, asks, trade prices. But in general, one can think of $S_t$ as a filtration or information at time $t$.

Comment: @courageousmartingale  Thank you for your response. Let me ponder this a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: @RameshKadambi Sure let me know if you have questions about my answer. I realized that I made a mistake when I wrote $E[Y]=1$. I meant to write $E[E[V|S_t]]=E[V]$. From there you can deduce the value $c$ for discrete cases like $\{Z_t>A\}\in S_t$.